# Masonry layout method not correctly arranging items in mobile

Tags: masonry

I've tried finding the solution to my problem but came up with nothing, so forgive me if this has been covered elsewhere.

I'm using Masonry for a client's site that I'm currently developing. In any viewport size that is 768px or wider, there are two element widths: 20% and 40%; when sizing down to mobile, i.e. up to 767px, the element sized at 20% becomes 50% and the one at 40% becomes 100%.

**The problem is that, in mobile view, Masonry doesn't always put two of the 50% elements into a row, so the grid becomes broken up.**

Here's a link to the dev site and Masonry grid: http://176.32.230.48/maxence.io/#work

Here's my CSS for the two different grid-item sizes:

```
  .grid-item,
  .grid-sizer {
    width: 20%;

    @include media(xs-max) {
      width: 50%;
    }

  }

  .grid-item-lg {
    width: 40%;

    @include media(xs-max) {
      width: 100%;
    }

  }
```

Here's the relevant block of jQuery:

```
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
});
```

I'm also using the Masonry `layout` method on window resize:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth < 768) {
        $('#grid').masonry('layout');
    }
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: "Sorry" but it always works fine for me (with reduced scren, with my mobile...). Could you attach a screenshot or something else?

Comment: So when you are looking in mobile view, **all** the 50% width columns are sat alongside each other? I'm not seeing this in both reduced desktop screen and mobile – here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9c0pa81alyn1fk/Screenshot%202016-03-21%2019.07.52.png?dl=0).

Comment: Here's a screenshot of both sizes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uoya0xkijxnp69l/so2.png?dl=0 & https://www.dropbox.com/s/1o0c5n03y1wqfjm/so.png?dl=0 . Maybe your problem is that if in mobile the rows are: 100%, 50%, 100%, 50%... your '50%' divs could no be together because the 100% elements "prevents" it. Is that what you desire?

Comment: Yep @JP.Aulet, that's the layout but it was my understanding that Masonry would fetch the 50% width elements and combine them to create a _row_ of sorts.